# ЕГЭ информатика C4 и C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl

Муниципальный этап олимпиады по информатике проводился для учеников 7–11-х классов. Все ученики участвовали в общем конкурсе. Каждый участник олимпиады мог набрать от 0 до 400 баллов. По положению об олимпиаде победителем признаётся участник, набравший наибольшее
количество баллов, при условии, что им набрано больше половины возможных баллов. Победителей может быть несколько, если это количество баллов наберут несколько человек; а может и не быть совсем, если никто не наберёт больше половины.

Напишите эффективную по времени работы и по используемой памяти программу (укажите используемую версию языка программирования, например, Borland Pascal 7.0), которая будет определять фамилию и имя лучшего участника, не ставшего победителем олимпиады. Если следующий за баллом победителей один и тот же балл набрали несколько человек или
если победителей нет, а лучших участников несколько (в этом случае они же являются искомыми), то должно выдаваться только число искомых участников. Гарантируется, что искомые участники (участник) имеются.

На вход программе сначала подаётся число участников олимпиады N (N<10000). В каждой из следующих N строк находится результат одного из участников олимпиады в следующем формате:

```
<Фамилия> <Имя> <класс> <баллы>
```

где `<Фамилия>` – строка, состоящая не более чем из 20 не пробельных символов; `<Имя>` – строка, состоящая не более чем из 15 не пробельных символов; `<класс>` – число от 7 до 11; `<баллы>` – целое число от 0 до 400 набранных участником баллов. `<Фамилия>` и `<Имя>, <Имя> и <класс>`, а также `<класс> и <баллы>` разделены одним пробелом. Пример входной строки:

```
Иванов Пётр 10 275
```

Программа должна выводить через пробел Фамилию и имя искомого участника или их число. Пример выходных данных:

```
Кузнецов Иван
Второй вариант выходных данных:
4
```

Собственно сабж можно ли использовать STL?
http://pastebin.com/PGsPGF60

Comment: STL — часть языка, не вижу, почему его использование может быть не разрешено. Хотя, конечно, в жюри сидят тоже люди, так что всё возможно.

Comment: Просто кто то говорит мол, на кой черт тебе решать эти задачи если там есть уже половина готовых тулсов(в STL), но писать на чистом C, тоже вариант для меня не очень хороший.

Comment: STL предоставляет простейшие алгоритмы. Если олимпиадная задача решается применением одного из них в лоб — стыд и позор составителям.

Comment: Осталось это объяснить проверяющим...

Comment: @avengerweb использовать можно, но в С4 уменьшают баллы за использование контейнеров\структур данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочитал, тоже стало интересно. Поводов для запрета, пробежавшись по правилам, я не нашёл, скорее всего можно. Но тут лучше уточнить! Вот ссылка для обратной связи с представителями ЕГЭ: http://ege.edu.ru/ru/feedback/. Помни, что тут есть и человеческий фактор! Один человек может засчитать, а другой - нет.

P.S. Если подумаешь подавать на апелляцию по каким либо причинам, то знай - иногда находят ошибку в другом задании и баллов становится только меньше!